# Sticky footer bootstrap on mobile

Tags: css, footer

In my project I'm trying to style footer (not fixed) that fill bottom page.
It works well but on mobile (in particular on portrait) I get the body background color after the footer.

My master page:

```css
html {
  position:relative;
  min-height:100%;
}
body {
  padding-bottom:60px;   
  padding-top:50px;
}
.footer {
  background:#101010;
  color:#9d9d9d;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px; 
  line-height: 60px; 
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="mycontent" class="container body-content">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>             
</div>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="text-muted">
       xxxxxx yyyyyy  zzzzzz
    </span>
  </div>
</footer>
```

What is the mistake ?

Comment: Add `margin:0px;` to `body {}`

Comment: tks but nothing change...